# Ionic Angular - Signup Issues

Tags: php, angularjs

Controller for sign-up

```
.controller('signupCtrl', 

function($scope,$http,$ionicPopup,$state,$ionicHistory) {

    $scope.signup=function(data){
            var link = 'http://localhost/b_data/server/signup.php';
            $http.post(link, {n : data.name, un : data.username, ps : data.password , ph: data.phone , add : data.address , pin : data.pincode })
            .then(function (res){   
                $scope.response = res.data.result; 
                if($scope.response.created=="1"){   
                    $scope.title="Account Created!";
                    $scope.template="Your account has been successfully created!";

                    //no back option
                    $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
                        disableAnimate: true,
                        disableBack: true
                    });
                    $state.go('login', {}, {location: "replace", reload: true});

                }else if($scope.response.exists=="1"){
                    $scope.title="Email Already exists";
                    $scope.template="Please click forgot password if necessary";

                }else{
                    $scope.title="Failed";
                    $scope.template="Contact Our Technical Team";
                }

                var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                        title: $scope.title,
                        template: $scope.template
                });


            });

    }
})
```

Backend signup.php few lines

```
if(isset($_GET["n"]) && isset($_GET["un"])&& isset($_GET["ps"])&& isset($_GET["ph"])&& isset($_GET["add"])&& isset($_GET["pin"]) )  {
    if( !empty($_GET["n"])  && !empty($_GET["un"])&& !empty($_GET["ps"])&& !empty($_GET["ph"])&& !empty($_GET["add"])&& !empty($_GET["pin"])  ){
 //rest of my db saving code
} }
```

As per debugging there is no issue i found in angular as well as php code, when debugging i found in php **$_GET['n']** is not working so the rest of get codes.

Sort this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you're using $_GET in php. You should use $_POST in php since in angular you're using $http.post.

**JS**

```
var json = {n : data.name, un : data.username, ps : data.password , 
           ph: data.phone , add : data.address , pin : data.pincode };

// Update wrap object with curly bracket
$http.post(link, {data: json}).then(...);
```

**PHP**

```
// Added json decode
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$postData = json_decode($data);

$n = $postData->n;
```

Comment: When you're using $_POST, the format is different. Let me update my answer.

Comment: Yes, please update answer so that i can sort this problem

Comment: I just updated my answer. Try whether its working or not.

Comment: var json1 = {n : data.name, un : data.username, ps : data.password , ph: data.phone , add : data.address , pin : data.pincode };
   $http.post(link, data: json1)
   .then(function (res){

Updated code, giving error, 
''missing ) after argument list'' whereas i didn't found any mistake

Comment: Oh. I just forgot to wrap the object. Let me update my answer once again.

Comment: I'm not very familiar in php language. I just read some other tutorial that you need json_decode as well. $_POST isn't going to work. I just updated my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133011/discussion-between-divyam-solanki-and-digit).